# My cucumber module runner has parallel thread count= 3, but when I try trigger this module 10 browser instances are opened by default always

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, pom.xml

In my BDD framework, I have a module runner xml file where I have parallel thread count value = 3 and this module has 13 tcs. But everytime I trigger this module in local, 10 browser instances always opens instead of 3 instances. But in Azure pipeline it works fine according to the thread count given in module runner xml file

When triggered in local 3 browser instances have to open instead of 10. Is there any place where I need to change other than module runner
Please check the images below:

Comment: Can you provide minimal reproducible example for your issue?

Comment: Please don't use images in your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors